# c++ wizard creation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wizard

I'm trying to create a custom wizard project with c++ and visual studio 2010 and, it works well but, when I create a project using that wizard, it doesn't "inherit" the include and lib files I put in the wizard. The way I put the includes in the wizard is the same I do at any project: go to properties -> (left tree list) configuration properties -> VC++ Directories.
I suppose there's a file (like default.js or default.vcxproj) but I dont exactly know what I have to modify.
I'd be happy if you could give me some help with this.

Thanks in advance.